# Call C#.Net functions in Java using Web Services

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0

Guys I've a Situation here..

I've Developed a Website using C# .Net framework 4.0, and My Buddy is developing an Android Application for it (It's in Java language).

Problem is.

1. How to call the Functions created in C# language from Java
   Language?
2. If Possible, what are the prerequisites do this?

Waiting for valuable solutions from you guys,,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expose either WCF methods or Webservice methods from  the C# website developed and then call them via SOAP from your java development for andriod.

Google: http://www.google.co.za/search?ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+call+.net+WCF

This should give you a good start.